# Magento: PHP to Append contents to an option

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, customization

We have a "Custom Color" option on products in our Magento catalog. I currently have html in the Option title, so the shopper can click to open a modalbox showing the custom color options and details.

For example:

**Color:**

Black

Custom (See Color Options & Instructions) ← text in parenthesis is linked

Bare

However, the html shows in the order summary. So I would like to modify:
`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml`

to basically include this argument "If the Custom Option title is Color, and the option shown is "Custom" add this text after `(<a href="">See Color Options & Instructions</a>)` "

I'm familiar with using and modifying PHP, but not writing arguments from scratch.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Much thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to display html within your select option?

Comment: Yes. And currently it's working fine. However, I don't want the thread to show in the select option **on the order summary**

Comment: You could try to wrap your code in a if statment that check to see what page your on eg `if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view')` run your code

Comment: Place that within the select option title?

Comment: Can you add the custom code you added to select.phtml?

Comment: I'm sure I can - I just don't know how to properly write the PHP argument to insert the html, if the Choice is Color and the Option is Custom Color.

Comment: Could you add your custom code that you added to the select.phtml to your question above? Also I think you may need to do this in Javascript and not php since php doesnt know the current user selection until after it is posted to the server

Comment: I'm not trying to make the link dynamically appear if the user selects "custom color". I'm trying to programmatically append it to the option title when the option title is Custom Color. That way it won't appear on the order information, because it's not part of the option name itself. I didn't add any custom code to select.phtml yet. That's what I'm hoping to do

Comment: @R.S **Here's basically what I want to do, in plain language, using the Magento snippets to elaborate:**

IF `$_option->getTitle()` IS **Color** AND `options-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-container` IS **"Custom"** THEN ADD `(<a href="">See Color Options & Instructions</a>)` AFTER OPTION NAME

Hoping that helps clarify and someone can assist writing what I expect would be about one line of php.

Much thanks.

Comment: Can you add a screen capture or markup image?

Comment: @R.S I'm not sure what I would send a screen capture **of** ... I've not done this yet. I'm _trying_ to ... Here's a screen capture of what I currently have in the Options title: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kx8hnldabqgufp/option-title.png

Comment: @R.S I certainly appreciate your looking into this - if using a different means to discuss this would be simpler, please advise.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!! ... <?php if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Color') echo '(<a href="">See Color Options & Instructions</a>)' ?>